# How to pass datetime from view to controller in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Am trying to pass below data form my view to controller.

**Edited**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pathname = 'http://' + window.location.host;
  var Student = [
  { Name: "Vijay", ID: 1, DOB: "2010-12-09T08:00:00.000Z" },
  { Name: "Anand", ID: 2, DOB: "2010-12-09T08:00:00.000Z" }
  ];

  $.ajax({
    url: pathname + "/Home/UpadetStu",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(Student),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (result) { }, 
    failure: function (r, e, s) { alert(e); } 
  });

</script>



   [ObjectFilter(Param = "stuData", RootType = typeof(Stu[]))]
    public JsonResult UpadetStu(Stu[] stuData)
    {
        return this.Json(new { success = true });
    }

[DataContract]
public class Stu
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime? DOB { get; set; }

}
```

But in the controller am getting null for Name and ID , default datetime for DOB, I found that there is problem in passing datetime. Is there any better way to pass datetime from view to controller? do i miss any parsing?

Comment: What does your Action on your controller look like?

Comment: [ObjectFilter(Param = "studentData", RootType = typeof(Stu[]))]
        public JsonResult UpadetStudent(Stu[] studentData)
        {
            return this.Json(new { success = true });
        }   
Am using above code in controller.

Comment: What does your Stu object look like then? does it have a DOB Property? Have you verified what your jQuery.ajax is actually posting to your server, using firebug or fiddler?

Comment: This is how it look like.   
 [DataContract]
    public class Stu
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public DateTime DOB{ get; set; }
}

Comment: I just copied your code and tried and it is working just fine.. the only difference is I don't have that ObjectFilter.

Comment: with ObjectFilter it does not work right? so what changes i should do in my controller code? else could you post your controller code here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is `Thu Dec 9 13:30:00 UTC+0530 2010` can't be parsed into a valid datetime object in c#. You can try that by simply calling `DateTime.Parse("Thu Dec 9 13:30:00 UTC+0530 2010")` it will fail.

I would suggest that instead of returning that date format from the server you can better return the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format that looks like `2010-12-09T08:00:00.000Z`.

You can easily convert the long datetime format into ISO 8601 from javascript by,

```
new Date("Thu Dec 9 13:30:00 UTC+0530 2010").toJSON();
```

If you are using [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) library you can easily control the way in which the datetimes have to be serialized.

**UPDATE:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var Student = [
  { Name: "Vijay", ID: 1, DOB: "2010-12-09T08:00:00.000Z" },
  { Name: "Anand", ID: 2, DOB: "2010-12-09T08:00:00.000Z" }
  ];

  $.ajax({
    url: "/Home/Index",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(Student),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (result) { }, 
    failure: function (r, e, s) { alert(e); } 
  });

</script>

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Student[] students)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: var studentString = JSON.stringify(Student); itself will change format, "studentString" will have DOB in this format  2010-12-09T08:00:00.000Z only then why its not working?

Comment: I just tested with a simple textbox entering the datetime in ISO format and it worked fine

Comment: Please post more code then I can help to figure out where the issue is

Comment: By the way why you want to stringify the data? you can just use it as a plain object in $.post right?

Comment: I have posted all my code in the above question and comments. For some reason i don't want to use $.post. Please help me how to make this work by using above code.

Comment: You need JSON.Stringify I was wrong in that. Only the DateTime is not working in your case? I tested the complete thing and it's working just fine with the ISO format. I updated the answer though.

Comment: Could you post your controller code here? Did you use my controller code in your's? Please try to use my code in your sample.

Comment: Please post your code(js, controller action, model) in the question. Currently it is in comments.

Answer (score 0):

If your studentData object in your controller is null, the JSON.stringify(Student) is producing an object that is not proper JSON or an object that can not be parsed to your Stu object.

Verify that your JS Student object is correct, then verify the JSON you produce doing JSON.stringify