# ModelState.IsValid is always false because of datetime.now

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, kendo-grid

I have an ASP.NET MVC application and in the edit and create actions I set date field of my class by `datetime.now`. Everything works fine and I can add and edit records. But when I want to delete those records `ModelStata.IsValid` is always `false` and the error is `"The value '4/25/2015 9:34:39 AM' is not valid for register time."` Register time is display name of my field.

Here is my actions code:

```
public ActionResult Create([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, InvtGroups invtGroup)
{
    if (invtGroup != null && ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        invtGroup.DDate = DateTime.Now;
        repo.Insert(invtGroup);
    }
    return Json(new[] { invtGroup }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, InvtGroups invtGroup)
{
    if (invtGroup != null && ModelState.IsValid)
        repo.Delete(invtGroup);
    return Json(new[] { invtGroup }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
}
```

This is my Model (I'm using Entity Framework Code First):

```
public class InvtGroups : User
{
    [Key]
    [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR"), StringLength(21)]
    public string CGroupCode { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR"), StringLength(50)]
    public string CGroupName { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "BIGINT")]
    public Int64? LiCode1 { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "BIGINT")]
    public Int64? LiCode2 { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "BIGINT")]
    public Int64? LiCode3 { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "BIGINT")]
    public Int64? LiCode4 { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "BIGINT")]
    public Int64? LiCode5 { get; set; }
}
```

And the user class:

```
public class User
{
    [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR"), StringLength(20)]
    public string CUserNo { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "DATETIME")]
    public DateTime? DDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: And by the way this is the field: `public DateTime? DDate { get; set; }`

Comment: Did you specify DataType.DateTime attribute to the property?

Comment: Show model code as well

Comment: I added them to the question.

Comment: Try to give a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11185847/how-to-pass-datetime-from-view-to-controller-in-asp-net-mvc I'm not sure of course it's the same problem

Comment: Thanks Paolo, but it's unlikely. I'm not entering `Date` value by hand, I'm using `DateTime.Now`.

Comment: And another thing: I'm using Kendo Grid. May be it's causing the problem?

Comment: None of the models you have posted contain the "...is not valid for register time" custom error message. Are we missing some other info maybe?

Comment: why you need to validate the model when you delete? what you should care about in my opinion is the Id of the model and nothing else if correct or not, you can remove the ModelState.IsValid

Comment: I removed their display name for clarity, if that's what you mean? The `DDate` in `User` class is causing the problem.

Comment: Yes, Hadi. That's exactly what I'm going to do. :) Remove the cause! But still it's good to know where the error is coming. It might cause error further on.

Comment: in order to solve your problem permanently, you should specify the kendo culture in your layout view, if you want more details i can post it in the answer

Comment: Yes, please. I have many troubles with Kendo.

Comment: Why do you want to validate a model you have to delete ?

Comment: As I said above, I'll remove that validation code. But still I want to solve this problem. It might cause problems further on.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

1- _Layout.cshtml

```
 <script>
        kendo.culture("en-GB");
        var culture = kendo.culture();
        culture.calendar.patterns.d = "dd MMM yyyy"; // 25 Feb 2015
        culture.calendar.patterns.D = "dd MMM yyyy";
        culture.calendar.patterns.t = "HH:mm";   // 16:45
        culture.calendar.patterns.T = "HH:mm";
        culture.calendar.patterns.g = "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm";
        culture.calendar.patterns.G = "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm";
 </script>
```

2- Global.asax

```
   protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            CultureInfo info = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
            info.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd MMM yyyy";
            info.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern = "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm";
            info.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits = 2;
            info.NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator = ",";
            info.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalDigits = 2;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = info;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = info;
        }
```

the above code will setup the date format and also the number formatting for your whole application

3- you can read this for more information about how to add the [culture js files](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/definecultureinfo)

hope it will help you and if you still have any question, go ahead.

Comment: Thanks Hadi, I've already added kendo.culture.* file in my `_layout`. Do I still need to do this?

Comment: refer to the link in point 3, you can read the following: "If you examine the source code of the script for each culture, you will notice that each script just adds the culture info object to the the kendo.cultures mappings. You can easily define your own culture file and extend current kendo.cultures mapping. The only requirement is to follow the structure of the default culture information listed above."

Comment: Yes, I know. But when I've included the culture file I need, I don't have to add the above codes, do I?

Comment: you still experiencing the same error in the date format? 4/25/2015 as invalid date since your application waiting to get 25/4/2015 instead? if yes, then you need to forcefully tell your application to use the format you want, else you can discard the solution, but it might help others having same issue and they want to customize the date format.

Comment: I'm using `DateTime.Now`, so the app itself gives me the date and it shouldn't have any problem. Thanks for your time and comments Hadi.