# Getting date value null in ajax request

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, date

I am using Ajax request to send the value of date to my API Controller here is my ajax call

```
 $("#txtpdate").on("changeDate", function (e) {
        var Date =$('#txtpdate').val();
        console.log(Date);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: false,
            url: '/api/ServiceProvider/GetUpdatedPrice',
            data:{date: Date  },
            cache: false
        }).done(function (response) {

        });
});
```

And here is my api controller

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("GetUpdatedPrice")]
public  ServiceProviderDocuments GetUpdatedPrice(DateTime date)
{
    return  ServiceProviderDocumentsGateway.GetUpdatedPriceofBike(date);
}
```

I am getting the desired value in `console.log(Date)` but when I reached to the controller it is showing null value
please take a look on the below image
[image]

Comment: try this one - data: JSON.stringify({date: Date  })

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11185847/how-to-pass-datetime-from-view-to-controller-in-asp-net-mvc)!

Comment: What does `console.log(Date);` log to your console?

Comment: this  is showing in console 06/20/2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just solved by doing this

```
  var dt=$('#txtpdate').val();
    ko.toJSON({ date: new Date(dt)})
```

then you will get date in action.

Answer (score 0):

hi try to parse request into json and your date field into date like to:
new Date

```
 var promise=jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    }).promise();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the date parameter as DateTime, like:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("GetUpdatedPrice/{pDate:datetime}")]
public  ServiceProviderDocuments GetUpdatedPrice(DateTime pDate)
{
    return ServiceProviderDocumentsGateway.GetUpdatedPriceofBike(pDate);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

1. Change the type of the parameter to string:

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   [Route("GetUpdatedPrice")]
   public  ServiceProviderDocuments GetUpdatedPrice(string date)
   {
       //Convert date to Datetime here
   }
   ```
2. Change the `contentType` to:

   ```
   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
   ```
3. Stringify the `date`:

   ```
   data: JSON.stringify({ date: Date }),
   ```

Comment: still getting null in controller

Comment: @Gaurav_0093 This should works. Are you sure that you did all the steps? Can you show your updated code?

Comment: yes sir here is my code-
   $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json;',
                url: '/api/ServiceProvider/GetUpdatedPrice',
                data: JSON.stringify({ date: Date }),
                cache: false
            }).done(function (response) {
in controller
[HttpPost]
        [Route("GetUpdatedPrice")]
        public  ServiceProviderDocuments GetUpdatedPrice(string date)
        {
            return  ServiceProviderDocumentsGateway.GetUpdatedPriceofBike(date);

        }

Comment: @Gaurav_0093 Please show the updated code in your question. Edit your question and show your new code.

Comment: @S.Akbari-Sir this one is the updated code in my question

Comment: @Gaurav_0093 Have you tried to rebuild your project after changes?

Comment: -yes sir I had cleaned my project and rebuild project as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145859/discussion-between-gaurav-0093-and-s-akbari).

Comment: yes sir i have to parse the json formt
i will show you in code

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the date was a property of a object and the "set" was only "internal", so I remove it and now it's working.

After:

```
public DateTime DataInicialFiltro { get; internal set; }
```

Before:

```
public DateTime DataInicialFiltro { get; set; }
```